# Passing Date Values from Kendo DatePicker to controller using ajax is resulting in this "01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM" value passed to my controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-datepicker

This is my view code

```
<td>
            <div>
                @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.Start)
                <br />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.End)
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </td>
```

This is my Script

```
function downloadReport() {

    $("#popUpWindow").data("kendoWindow").center().open();

    var End = $("#End").val();
    var Start = $("#Start").val();


    var Dates = { start: Start, end: End }


    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("DownloadReport", "Report")",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ report : Dates }  ),
     success: function (result) {
       //some code
    },
     error: 
         function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //some code
    }
});
}
```

The value that I am receiving on my controller is 01/01/0001 12:00:00 Am.
The Values picked up by the script are in the format of dd/mm/yyyy. 
Why am I not able to pass the correct values? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue a number of times and have come up with a quick solution that seems to have worked for me when handling dates from kendo controls.

```
function parseDate(value, format) {
    if (value === null) {
        return '-';
    }
    else {

        if (format === null || format === undefined)
        {
            format = 'dd MMM yy'; 
        }

        return kendo.format("{0:" + format + "}", value);
    }
}
```

This function takes any `date` value and then you can specify the format you wish the returned value to be presented back eg. ddd, dd MMM yyyy etc.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I used this method to pass the date time values.

```
    $("#popUpWindow").data("kendoWindow").center().open();

    var End = $("#End").val().toString();


    var Start = $("#Start").val();



    var Dates = "{'start':'" + Start + "', 'end':'" + End + "'}";
```

I wasn't assigning the values properly to send from Ajax.That was the problem.
Thanks for your help @David